# Does having a pet help to cure your depression?

Tags: psychology, zoology, depression

According to the community based website [Curetogether](http://www.curetogether.com/depression/treatments/) spending time with a pet helps people with depression.

Is there peer reviewed research that makes the same recommendation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/4465998.stm) has an article about a [study with dolphins](http://www.bmj.com/content/331/7527/1231.abstract)

> A University of Leicester team **tested
> the effect of regular swimming
> sessions with dolphins** on 15 depressed
> people in a study carried out in
> Honduras.
>
> They found that **symptoms improved more
> among this group than among another 15
> who swam in the same area - but did
> not interact with dolphins.**
>
> All the volunteers who took part in
> the trial stopped taking
> antidepressant drugs or undergoing
> psychotherapy at least four weeks
> beforehand.
>
> Two weeks later, both groups showed
> improved mental health, but especially
> so among patients who had been
> swimming with the dolphins.

---

And [here is a study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15207440) about how a **cat improved depressive symptoms in elderly people**

> 28 subjects with chronic
> age-related disabilities living in a
> nursing home ... were assigned to
> a pet-therapy intervention group.
>
> **Results showed that patients with
> animal interaction had improved
> depressive symptoms** and a significant
> decrease in blood pressure values.

---

[This study](http://www.anthrozoology.org/animal_assisted_therapy_and_depression_in_adult_college_students) is about **animal-assisted therapy in adult college students**

> [The study] investigated the effects of
> animal-assisted therapy (A-AT) on
> self-reported depression in 44 college
> undergraduates.
>
> **Results confirmed the positive
> influence of A-AT** in this cohort.

---

Here is a study about "[The Effects of Animal-Assisted Therapy on Anxiety Ratings of Hospitalized Psychiatric Patients](http://psychservices.psychiatryonline.org/cgi/content/full/49/6/797)"

> This study examined whether a session
> of animal-assisted therapy reduced the
> anxiety levels of hospitalized
> psychiatric patients and whether any
> differences in reductions in anxiety
> were associated with patients'
> diagnoses.

It was concluded:

> **Animal-assisted therapy was associated
> with reduced state anxiety levels for
> hospitalized patients with a variety
> of psychiatric diagnoses**, while a
> routine therapeutic recreation session
> was associated with reduced levels
> only for patients with mood disorders.

Comment: What??? No studies with velociraptors? Damn...

Comment: Without a Velociraptor reference I can only go +1 for this (almost) excellent answer.